# Can we store HTML in attachment?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I am trying to save HTML in attachment, using mail kit I am downloading the attachment and store it in a database in `byte[]` for that I need to convert attachment in the stream but while converting HTML document in the stream it shows me zero length in stream for all other document code is working fine.

Below is the code which I am using:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
{
    if (attachment is MessagePart)
    {
        var rfc822 = (MessagePart)attachment;

        rfc822.Message.WriteTo(stream);
    }
    else
    {
        var part = (MimePart)attachment;

        part.ContentObject.DecodeTo(stream);
    }

    int length = Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length);
    attachments.strFileName = fileName;
    attachments.strAttachment = new byte[length];
    stream.Read(attachments.strAttachment, 0, length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewind the stream before you'll be able to read the content.

```
stream.Position = 0;
```